# Detect movement with an android device

Tags: android, orientation, augmented-reality, device-orientation

I'm developing an **Android 2.2** application.

I want to know when user moves device up or down, and when it moves to the left or to the right. The device will be at rest when mounted vertically. In other words, using the camera (Y axis along the camera's axis) for an augmented reality application where the rotation angles are needed:

```
remapCoordinateSystem(inR, AXIS_X, AXIS_Z, outR);
```

This is my code:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        accelValues = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        magneValues = event.values;

  updateOrientation(calculateOrientation());
}

private float[] calculateOrientation() {
    float[] values = new float[3];
    float[] R = new float[9];
    float[] outR = new float[9];

    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, accelValues, magneValues);
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(R, 
                                          SensorManager.AXIS_X, 
                                          SensorManager.AXIS_Z, 
                                          outR);

    SensorManager.getOrientation(outR, values);

    // Convert from Radians to Degrees.
    values[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[0]); // Azimuth, rotation around Z
    values[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[1]); // Pitch, rotation around X
    values[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(values[2]); // Roll, rotation around Y

    return values;
}
```

but I'm not sure how can I know if user moves device to the left or to the right.

And, **how can I know if user walk?**

There is an Azimuth, a Pitch and a Roll, but I don't know how can I use these values.

Any advice?

Comment: I have the same problem too, did you find a solution

Comment: No, I've asked this question 4 hours ago. I'm still waiting for an answer. If you find the solution, please tell me.